# Extract data from json file with Python

Tags: python, json

I have the following data in json file containing thousands of lines like this:
"{'X(Al)': 1e-07, 'X(Ti)': 1e-07, 'X(Co)': 0.2499998, 'X(Cr)': 0.2499998, 'X(Fe)': 0.2499998}": {'FCC_L12#1': 1.0}
and so on.
More generally, it is:
"{key1:value1, ..., key5:value5}":{key6:value6}, etc.
Somehow, {key6:value6} is a composite value of the composite key {key1:value1, ..., key5:value5}.
I need to extract specific values in array, e.g. value1, value2 from "{}" and value6 from {}, with the aim to plot FCC_L12 as a function of X(Al) and X(Ti)
Help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please edit the question so the `JSON` content is more readable. In the current version the separation between the keys and values fields is not that clear 
`{"key1": "value1", ..."keyn":  "valuen"}` Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following example of data in `JSON` file

> data =  {"{'X(Al)': 1e-07, 'X(Ti)': 1e-07, 'X(Co)': 0.2499998, 'X(Cr)':
> 0.2499998, 'X(Fe)': 0.2499998}": "{'FCC_L12#1': 1.0}",  "{'X(Al)': 1e-07, 'X(Ti)': 0.02000008, 'X(Co)': 0.22999982, 'X(Cr)': 0.22999982,
> 'X(Fe)': 0.22999982}": "{'FCC_L12#1': 0.983281013732619, 'FCC_L12#3':
> 0.01671898626738027}"}

you need to go over all the keys and values you have in the loaded dictionary containing that file data, then convert the string fields to a `JSON` object.
Below an example

```
 data =  {"{'X(Al)': 1e-07, 'X(Ti)': 1e-07, 'X(Co)': 0.2499998, 'X(Cr)':
0.2499998, 'X(Fe)': 0.2499998}": "{'FCC_L12#1': 1.0}",  "{'X(Al)': 1e-07, 'X(Ti)': 0.02000008, 'X(Co)': 0.22999982, 'X(Cr)': 0.22999982,
'X(Fe)': 0.22999982}": "{'FCC_L12#1': 0.983281013732619, 'FCC_L12#3':
0.01671898626738027}"}
for key, value in data.items():
    print("Original key type", type(key))
    new_key_dict = eval(key)
    print("New key content type", type(new_key_dict))
    # Then you do the same for the value as it also contains a JSON data serialized as a string
    new_value_dict = eval(value)
```

If you try the code above on the mentioned sample data you will get the folowing result

```
Original key type <class 'str'>
New key content type <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: Just one more thing: the data are not exactly the ones you considered. I show you here just the first line for clarity: data = {"{'X(Al)': 1e-07, 'X(Ti)': 1e-07, 'X(Co)': 0.2499998, 'X(Cr)': 0.2499998, 'X(Fe)': 0.2499998}": {'FCC_L12#1': 1.0}} so the code new_value_dict = eval(value) does not work. At the end my goal is to plot the value of FCC_L12 as a function of the values of X(Al) and X(Ti). And I have thousands as above in my json file.

Comment: @Stephane Please don't forget to up-vote or select the answer as accepted answer your question if it is the case. Thanks